# Select record Details and its own table count in select statements where Each record have its own table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with `recordid` ,`record name`, and an extra column with its corresponding Table name. Each record have its own table . Now I want to select `record name` , `id` and its corresponding table count using select query in sql. Please help me ..

Thank You

i have a table with name 'records' like

recordid     name      description       table name
    ------------------------------------------------
     1       record1      description1     tb_name1

```
 2       record2      description1     tb_name2
```

Each record Have A table.For eg record 1 has a table name as tb_name1 and record2 has a table name as tb_name2

**in tb_name1**

### id   recordid    name       dob       address      entrydate

```
1    1           xxx      13-6-2011   xxx           7/9/2013
2    1           xxx      13-6-2011   xxx           8/9/2013
3    1           xxx      13-6-2011   xxx           8/9/2013
4    1           xxx      13-6-2011   xxx           9/9/2013
```

**like that in  in tb_name2**

### id   recordid    name       dob       address      entrydate

```
1    2           xxx      13-6-2011   xxx           6/9/2013
2    2           xxx      13-6-2011   xxx           7/9/2013
3    2           xxx      13-6-2011   xxx           8/9/2013
```

i want a result like

### recordid     name      description     count

1         record1     description1     4
 2         record2     description1     3

4,3 are the row count of its corresponding table..

Comment: I may not be getting the full picture here. Are you saying each record has a table? Is there a set number of tables that select from or is each dynamic?

Comment: ya Each record have a table..i want to get the record details and its corresponding table count. thanking u.

Comment: If each record corresponds to only one table then what do you mean by table count ? Can you give sample data ?

Comment: sample data will be more useful to solve your query.

Comment: Clarify please. "Each record have its own table"???? Post your table structures & examples of your records, and what you actually want to get in your query results. Otherwise, voting to close.

Comment: You will need to dynamically generate your SQL query based on the value of that 3rd column. Direct SQL will not get what you want, Either write a TSQL procedure or write the same logic in your front end language.

Comment: iam new in stack overflow... sorry for the mistakes

Comment: How accurate do the counts need to be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**If** you can tolerate the counts not being guaranteed to be 100% accurate<sup>1</sup>, then you can join to the [`sys.partitions`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175012.aspx) catalog view, which describes it's `rows` column thus:

> Indicates the approximate number of rows in this partition.

So you'd have a join something like this:

```
select recordid,name,description,rowcount
from
   [unnamedfirsttableinquestion] t
        inner join
  (select object_id,SUM(rows)
    from sys.partitions group by object_id) u (oid,rowcount)
     on
         u.oid = OBJECT_ID(t.tablename)
```

---

<sup>1</sup>In practice, you normally can tolerate this - either:

- the table isn't subject to frequent updates, in which case the row count is quite likely to be up to date, or,
- the table is subject to frequent updates in which case by the time you know the answer, it's probably changed anyway.

Comment: ya it should be accurate...